# Extract substring (that contains a dynamic portion) from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, extract

Say I have the following sub-string that resides inside a larger string:

> My name is `{name}`

`{name}` is just a placeholder because it might be different every time the program is run. For example:

> **Run #1:** Hi there, my name is *Phil!* Nice to meet you.
>
> **Run #2:** My name is *Robert*, and I am really, really cool.

How can I (in the most concise way possible):

1. Verify that the string contains the `My name is {name}` sub-string? (case insensitive)
2. Extract the `{name}` part into a separate variable that I can do something with?

Comment: Is the name always a string of alphabetical characters, and always followed by a period? Also, how many times can it occur?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yes, always a string of alphabetical characters. Any non-alphabetical character may follow it. The sub-string `My name is {name}` could occur many times.

Comment: May be you try this .. take `Hi there My Name is ` in one string and `Nice To meet you` in one string the desired name in One string Concatinate them

Comment: @looser The string is not guaranteed to have `Hi there!` and `Nice to meet you.`. See my most recent edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String s = "Hi there! My name is Phil. Nice to meet you.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("my name is (\\w*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("No match to " + s);
}
```

The `(\\w*)` creates a capture group of all "word characters". More information can be found at the docs for [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

P.S. It's been hard to track your requirements through all the edits. I hope this matches what you need. If not, it should be fairly straightforward to modify it.

Comment: Thanks. (Sorry for all the edits. Was trying to make the question clearer.)

Comment: What if I want to extract only Signin from the below string:
String = "MyAccountSigninSignupSupportJira"; I tried using same but did not get any luck. Can someone please help me !

Comment: @RanjanGupta - I'm not sure what behavior you are after, what you tried, or why it didn't work. I suggest that you post a separate question and provide those details. You're more likely to get an answer that way.